# How can I delete Authentication parameter from swagger in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui

I had a spring boot project that uses both spring security and swagger UI.

The Main problem is when i **use Authentication in parameter of controller method** like this

```
    @PutMapping("/")
    public UserRestDTo update(Authentication auth, @RequestBody UserRestDTo user) {
        ...
    }
```

I got the Authentication object in the request parameter of swagger-UI like this
[swagger result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m1od.png)

- **first**: Is this a bug in swagger?
- **second**: is there any security problem that can affect my project?
- **third**: how to remove the Authentication object from the request?

finally: ***thanks for the help:D.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution :

```
@PutMapping("/")
    public UserRestDTo update(@RequestBody UserRestDTo user) throws AbstractWebException {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        ...
    }
```

but i steel need to know if is the old method **can effect badly on the security of my project** or it's just a swagger bug.